# Adding a bracketed descendants count to each list item (LI). Skip those LI which don’t have other list items inside

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function f() {
  var count = document.getElementById('t1').childElementCount;
  alert(count);
  for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    alert("[" + i + "]");
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>About Animals
    <ul id="t1" onclick="f()">
      <li>Mammals
        <ul id="t2" onclick="f()">
          <li>Cows</li>
          <li>Donkeys</li>
          <li>Dogs</li>
          <li>Tigers</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Others
        <ul id="t3" onclick="f()">
          <li>Snakes</li>
          <li>Birds</li>
          <li>Lizards</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>About Fish
    <ul id="t4" onclick="f()">
      <li>About Aquarium Fishes
        <ul id="t5" onclick="f()">
          <li>Guppy</li>
          <li>Scalare</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Sea Fish
        <ul id="t6" onclick="f()">
          <li>Sea Trout</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Above is my code but it's not showing any output. I want the code to be displayed in the following manner as shown below.

- About Animals [9]

  - Mammals [4]

    - Cows
    - Donkeys
    - Dogs
    - Tigers
  - Others [3]

    - Snakes
    - Birds
    - Lizards
- About Fish [5]

  - About aquarium fishes [2]

    - Guppy
    - Scalare
  - Sea fish [1]

    - Sea trout

Comment: I don't understand how exactly and where the output should be generated from what I see here. Can you be more precise as to show the expected output more clearly and describe it piece by piece. E.g. should it be just printed to the console? What do the numbers in brackets mean? Which part should be filtered etc.

Comment: Like you can see the display pattern near Animals [9] is being displayed because it contains 9 children li inside it and mammals have 4 and so on.

Comment: @newbie Do you want those numbers to be displayed as a part of HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repleace `onclick="f()"` with `f(this)`

Add change you function with this

```
function f(elmnt) {
   alert(elmnt.getElementsByTagName("li").length);
}
```

```js
var alladdnum =document.querySelectorAll(".addnum");
for (i = 0; i < alladdnum.length; i++) { 
  var span = alladdnum[i].getElementsByTagName("span");
  span[0].innerHTML += ' '  + alladdnum[i].getElementsByTagName("li").length;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="addnum"><span>About Animals</span>
    <ul id="t1" onclick="f(this)">
      <li class="addnum"><span>Mammals</span>
        <ul id="t2" onclick="f()">
          <li>Cows</li>
          <li>Donkeys</li>
          <li>Dogs</li>
          <li>Tigers</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="addnum"><span>Others</span>
        <ul id="t3" onclick="f()">
          <li>Snakes</li>
          <li>Birds</li>
          <li>Lizards</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="addnum"><span>About Fish</span>
    <ul id="t4" onclick="f()">
      <li class="addnum"><span>About Aquarium Fishes</span>
        <ul id="t5" onclick="f()">
          <li>Guppy</li>
          <li>Scalare</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="addnum"><span>Sea Fish</span>
        <ul id="t6" onclick="f()">
          <li>Sea Trout</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @brk Please Try now

Comment: still now not working, click on `Sea Fish` it will alert 5 , also instead of alert the value need to placed beside the list head

Comment: First, it shows 1 than for click `Sea Fish` then 5 for `About Fish` because of it `About Fish` also clicked. `Sea Fish` is under of `About Fish`.

Comment: But I need to display beside the list head.

Comment: I have updated my code. please check. now it is displayed beside the list head.

Comment: Is there any other way doing this recursively with the help dom concept

Comment: do you mean without javascript?

Comment: No I mean using the concept of dom in javascript. Starting with the parent and using recursive calls going inside and accessing the children. Then coming out and returning the number of children.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
<ul>
    <li class="group" onclick="f(this)"> About Animals<span class="length"></span>
        <ul id="t1"  onclick="f(this)">
            <li class="group item" onclick="f(this)">Mammals<span class="length"></span>
                <ul id="t2" onclick="f(this)">
                    <li class="item">Cows</li>
                    <li class="item">Donkeys</li>
                    <li class="item">Dogs</li>
                    <li class="item">Tigers</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="group item" onclick="f(this)">Others<span class="length"></span>
                <ul id="t3" onclick="f(this)">
                    <li class="item">Snakes</li>
                    <li class="item">Birds</li>
                    <li class="item">Lizards</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="group item" onclick="f(this)">About Fish<span class="length"></span>
        <ul id="t4" onclick="f(this)">
            <li class="group item" onclick="f(this)">About Aquarium Fishes<span class="length"></span>
                <ul id="t5" onclick="f(this)">
                    <li class="item">Guppy</li>
                    <li class="item">Scalare</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="group item" onclick="f(this)">Sea Fish<span class="length"></span>
                <ul id="t6" onclick="f(this)">
                    <li class="item">Sea Trout</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

 function f(element){
        if(element && element.classList.contains("group")) {
            var lengthElem = element.getElementsByClassName("length")[0];
            var itemLength = element.getElementsByClassName("item").length;
            lengthElem.textContent = "["+itemLength+"]";
        }

    }
```